# Data not matching when fetching from Google Analytics API (python)

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, segment

I'm making a script to pull data from Google Analytics API v4. The script works fine. However, when validating the data by comparing GA with my fetched data I can see some **discrepancies**. Not too different but I don't understand why is not the same.

Just to mention that I'm using dynamic segments on my script which has the exact same condition as the segment I have in my GA view.
The segment is just filtering spam traffic by only including traffic where session duration > 1sec.

Here is the structure I'm pulling:

```
body={
"reportRequests":[
{
"viewId": view_id,
"dimensions":[{"name": "ga:date"},{"name": "ga:sourceMedium"},{"name": "ga:campaign"},{"name": "ga:adContent"},{"name": "ga:channelGrouping"},{"name": "ga:segment"}],
"dateRanges":[
{
"startDate":"2018-12-16",
"endDate":"2018-12-20"
}],
"metrics":[{"expression":"ga:sessions","alias":"sessions"}],
"segments":[
{
"dynamicSegment":
{
    "name": "sessions_no_spam",
    "userSegment":
    {
    "segmentFilters":[
    {
        "simpleSegment":
        {
        "orFiltersForSegment":
        {
            "segmentFilterClauses": [
            {
            "metricFilter":
            {
                "metricName":"ga:sessionDuration",
                "operator":"GREATER_THAN",
                "comparisonValue":"1"
            }
            }]
        }
        }
    }]
    }
}
}]
}]
}).execute()
```

Not sure if the answer to my question will be more conceptual rather than technical but just in case I'm also including the function where I bulk the results in my database:

```
def print_results(no_spam_traffic):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(database = 'web_insights_data', user = 'XXXX', password = 'XXXXX', host = 'XXX', port = 'XXXXX')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for report in no_spam_traffic.get('reports', []):
        for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
            gadate = row['dimensions'][0]
            gadate = gadate[0:4]+'/'+gadate[4:6]+'/'+gadate[6:8]
            gasourcemedium = row['dimensions'][1]
            gacampaign = row['dimensions'][2]
            gaadcontent = row['dimensions'][3]
            gachannel = row['dimensions'][4]
            gasessions = row['metrics'][0]['values'][0]

            cursor.execute("SELECT * from GA_no_spam_traffic where gadate = %s AND sourcemedium = %s AND campaign = %s AND adcontent = %s", (str(gadate),str(gasourcemedium),str(gacampaign),str(gaadcontent)))
            if len(cursor.fetchall())>0:        #update old entries
                cursor.execute("UPDATE GA_no_spam_traffic set sessions = %s where gadate = %s AND sourcemedium = %s AND campaign = %s AND adcontent = %s", (str(gasessions),str(gadate),str(gasourcemedium),str(gacampaign),str(gaadcontent)))
                connection.commit()
            else:                               #Insert new rows
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO GA_no_spam_traffic (gadate,sourcemedium,campaign,adcontent,channel,sessions) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (gadate,gasourcemedium,gacampaign,gaadcontent,gachannel,gasessions))
                connection.commit()

    connection.close()
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?
Thanks!!

Comment: What kind of discrepancies are you seeing between the UI and your API pulls? GA typically uses sampling to quickly display values. Have you tried specifying your sampling level?

Comment: Yes, if you are seeing small discrepancies I'd look to sampling issues.

Comment: Thanks! I shouldn't have sampling issues because I don't have much sessions. With the segment I'm having <90000 during a 35 days period.
Just in case I added a parameter to my query: "samplingLevel": "LARGE" but still there is a small discrepancy: 84925 sessions (from my script) vs 86120 (from analytics)
The filters I have on my property shouldn't affect, do they? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I managed to improve it, although it's not exact. But well, it's an acceptable discrepancy. I had a problem with the page size so I increased the pagesize parameter.

Here's the link to the pagination section from a google guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#pagination
Thanks